# Have a feature branch in git and can't merge master after reverting a merge from a different branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-flow

We have implemented a kind of git flow workflow in our company but not everyone is actually using git flow yet so there are some hiccups. Here is one.

A colleague was working on a feature branch and needed some bug fixes that are currently in master and develop. However, he got confused and merged develop into his feature branch instead of master, thus getting a number of unwanted features. He pushed to our git server.

Now, I saw his error and we tried correcting it. We reverted the merge commit

```
git revert -m 1 hismergecommit
```

and undid his merge. However, if he tries to merge master into his branch, he's told that there's nothing to merge! This appears to be due to the fact that master had previously been merged into development, prior to his gaff.

[image]

The picture gives an idea what it looks like.

Is there a way to merge in master to his feature without reseting his feature branch to before his bad merge or cherry picking all the commits in master?

EDIT:

I'd like to add that although he has pushed the branch to the server, nobody else has pulled it so it isn't "dangerous" to rewrite the history in this case, I'd just like to know if there's a good way to fix these kinds of issues should they arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with resetting the branch?

I have replicated the problem like this:

```
git init .

echo line > file
git add file 
git commit . -m "added file"

# Create the branches
git branch -t feature
git branch -t dev

git checkout dev
echo dev-line >> file
git commit . -m "added dev-line"
echo test > another-file
git add another-file
git commit . -m "another file"
git merge master

git checkout feature
echo test > feature-file
git add feature-file
git commit . -m "feature commit"

# merge dev into the feature branch
git merge dev

# undo the merge
git revert -m 1 e04d9159fa54aaf06e7329a7799cc58fc3334d34


# Now we have this mess:
* add2b8ea6583c355cc49048b65f07ce697d9c01c Revert "Merge branch 'dev' into feature"
*   e04d9159fa54aaf06e7329a7799cc58fc3334d34 Merge branch 'dev' into feature
|\  
| *   b506d08d62b6434e1383d50eccc26d5a933703e2 Merge branch 'master' into dev
| |\  
| | * 18671754b703561587c3875d0f56bd99a2e08c74 another file
| * | 978c2f52d1cd10fc27af2f0a59f295d99ac20e28 added dev-line
| |/  
* | ac794379e0a2038822ca772ffb3098b5270f22c2 feature commit
|/  
* d416cf0e4a84517871e93e0ac13a60c586353a79 added file

# Now when we try to merge master we get 'Already up-to-date.' This is because master was already merged.
git merge master
```

The cleanest way imo, is to reset the feature branch before the commits.

```
git reset --hard ac794379e0a2038822ca772ffb3098b5270f22c2
git merge master

*   4fa1459304668ec7b8d61eed052f9161fce02435 Merge branch 'master' into feature
|\  
| * 18671754b703561587c3875d0f56bd99a2e08c74 another file
* | ac794379e0a2038822ca772ffb3098b5270f22c2 feature commit
|/  
* d416cf0e4a84517871e93e0ac13a60c586353a79 added file
```

Then force push to the server.

Comment: server prevents force pushing unfortunately. we can, however, ask an admin to delete the branch on the server and then we can reset locally.

Comment: You can delete a remote branch by pushing (without force). `git push origin :feature` deletes 'feature' on the origin (local branch stays unmodified). Then you can push the branch again ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately our server's configured to not let any rewriting of history done. You can't even amend a commit then try to push if you've already done so.

Comment: I think under 'normal' circumstances your solution is best though, it's just out particular environment is a bit limiting.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call c1 the commit just before the merge. You could try to reset the feature branch to c1, then merge master into the feature branch and push the result.

```
git reset --hard c1
git merge master
git commit -am "some stuff"
git pull origin feature_branch
git push origin feature_branch
```